parent rig deletes after save
I have a rigged model where the entire rig is fine except a piece of the face. When I animate the rig, the teeth are never parented. When I do parent the teeth to the rig it works fine, so I'll save it. But when I open the saved file its unparented, as if being unparented is some how set to default. Same with deleting empty collections. When I save the file and reopen it, the deleted collections are still there.

Try cleaning up your scene after you deleting collections and objects? File > Clean up > Unused Data-blocks

That didn't work. Thanks for responding though. i am still trying to figure it out. I downloaded a newer version of blender ( 3.6.7 to 4.1.1) and that didn't work either. But I discovered that if I upload the file to my work computer which uses Blender 3.6 as well, it works fine.  But it doesn't work on my home pc which is where i do the majority of my blender work.

If it works on the other PC, try loading the factory settings, this will help in most cases.
File > Defaults > Load Factory Defaults
